# Wireless Atheros AR5B97 not shown in lspci

Tags: wireless, drivers

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, in Oracle VM virtual box ver.4.3.18 r96516.

Wireless card is built in my Acer Aspire laptop 5745DG (3D), Windows shows it as "Atheros AR5B97 Wireless Network Adapter". I do not see this wireless card when I run `lspci` in Ubuntu. I think my Wifi does not work in Ubuntu.

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:06.0 USB controller: Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)
00:0b.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
```

How can I get Ubuntu to recognize my wireless? Where can I find the driver for this wireless card for Ubuntu?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in Advance, Regards.

Comment: Can you check your Ubuntu version with ``lsb_release -a``?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.
The setting is already configured as NAT.

Comment: any other reason why I cant see wireless ?

Comment: lsb_release -a   shows Ubnutu 14.04.1 LTS (NO LSB MODULES ARE AVAILABLE)

Answer (score 2):

I think Virtualbox hides your real network adapters from Ubuntu. It routes your active network connection to `Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller` by default (the VM network settings should be configured as NAT)